# How to position sprites in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently using PointCloud to generate a particle system but within that I would like one single sprite that floats in the position of my indication. When I tried using this three.js example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_sprites I found that the Orthographic Camera limited my ability to still zoom about.

```
        var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer, particles, geometry, materials =[], i, h, color, sprite, size;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.001 );

            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            sprite = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "disc.png" );


            for ( i = 0; i < 5000; i ++ ) {

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                vertex.x = 2000 * Math.random() - 1000;
                vertex.y = 2000 * Math.random() - 1000;
                vertex.z = 2000 * Math.random() - 1000;

                geometry.vertices.push( vertex );

            }

            // size = Math.random() * 10;

            material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 5, sizeAttenuation: false, map: sprite, alphaTest: 0.5, transparent: true } );

            particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );
            scene.add( particles );

            var map2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "astronaut.png" );
            var material2 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map2, color: 0xffffff, fog: true } );
            var sprite2 = new THREE.Sprite( material2 );
            sprite2.position.x = 0;
            sprite2.position.y = 0;
            sprite2.position.z = 498;
            scene.add( sprite2 );


            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }
        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

            }

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();


        }

        function render() {

            var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            h = ( 360 * ( 1.0 + time ) % 360 ) / 360;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

My attempt at solving it was:

```
var map2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "astronaut.png" );
var material2 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map2, color: 0xffffff, fog: true } );
var sprite2 = new THREE.Sprite( material2 );
sprite2.position.x = 0;
sprite2.position.y = 0;
sprite2.position.z = 498;
scene.add( sprite2 );
```

Right now the sprite is in the center of the screen when I first load but instantly disappears when I begin to move the camera. Ideally, I would like the astronaut.png sprite to move with the other particles but if this is difficult, having him always fixed to the center of the screen would work fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this on my own. I created a second THREE.Geometry and THREE.Vector3 an positioned it with vertices.

```
geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
var vertex2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -50);

geometry2.vertices.push( vertex2 );

var material2 = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 100, sizeAttenuation: false, map: map2, alphaTest: 0.5, transparent: true } );

particles2 = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry2, material2 );
scene.add( particles2 );
```

Comment: wait so what is your main problem, everything moving off the screen or having the astronaut track with the rest?

Comment: It was having the astronaut track with the rest. I do see where you were going with your answer, however, the extreme panning of viewport is what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your values for mouse position would be way too high for camera positions. OpenGL works on the (-1,1) (1,1) (1,-1) (-1,-1) bounding rectangle as a unit. Pixels for your cursor position are in screen pixels like 350,720 etc.

When you increment by the half distance, your numbers are still too large.  So here you have to divide by your width/height:

```
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX / window.innerWidth- camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY /window.innerHeight- camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
```

assuming your GL portal is the same size as the window.